# Will I void the manufacturer warranty on a 2012 Nissan if get aftermarket cruise-control installed?

Tags: cruise-control, warranty

I bought a used 2012 Nissan from a Nissan dealership, and it's still covered under the original manufacturer warranty.

It didn't come with cruise control, and now I'm looking at getting a [Rostra cruise control](http://www.rostra.com/universal-aftermarket-cruise-control-by-rostra.php) installed by a local garage.

Will installing an after-market cruise-control system void the manufacturer's warranty on my car?

Comment: No, probably not, but it probably *will* void your warranty when the cruise control randomly decides to go full throttle and put your car in a tree (I jest, of course; I'm sure there are some after market cruise controls out there that are actually decent quality).

Comment: @Sam Whited The issue is that there are no other alternatives for me to have a cruise control system installed. I've asked Nissan dealerships in my city and other cities in my area, and none of their service departments have the ability to install cruise control. I even asked about this before I bought the car, and everyone at the dealership told me that I would need to get cruise control installed at a mechanic/garage.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a cruise control should not affect your warranty. Even if it did, it would possibly only affect the part of the warranty the part touches. What I mean by that is, for instance, if you installed an aftermarket steering wheel, it would probably void the warranty on the air bag system because the air bag system is associated with the stock steering wheel. (This is just something I'm throwing out there, but hopefully you get the idea.) It wouldn't void the warranty on the entire vehicle. As for the Rostra CC, it appears it doesn't replace anything, nor should there be any hacking of the stock wiring harness, so there should be no worry about voiding the warranty. A key question you can ask yourself is, if you install it, can it be removed without any show of damage to the vehicle (do you have to damage any part of the vehicle to get it installed)? If the answer is yes, you should have no worries. The Rostra appears to fall into that category. (And before someone says, "Well you could put a cam shaft in a car and take it back out and leave it like it was" ... I would say to you, no you cannot. There are a huge amount of tell tale signs someone has been intrusive on an engine, such as disrupted seals, cleanliness/dirt removal in certain areas, etc. It is usually *very* easy to tell if an engine has been opened up.)

Answer (score 1):

Your Nissan was built, tested and sold as an entity. Any changes to a vehicle would not be accepted by most, if not all, vehicle manufactures which they do not have any control or imput to and would void the warranty. Unless you know they are manufacturer approved fitments, you should check with the manufacturer, do not have them fitted. There have been court cases here in the UK where innocuous extras have been fitted, followed by a breakdown of the vehicle in some other area of its construction, and exclusion from warranty has been upheld. In Europe we have what is know as 'Block Exemption' in motor vehicle repair. A person with recognised formal qualifications in motor vehicle repair, using original manufacturers replacement parts - oils - greases - and anything else used - would not invalidate the vehicles warranty in servicing the vehicle. But if any of these requirements are not satisfied the warranty would not be void. *Fit an after market oil filter, have trouble with the engine, no warranty.* There are bound to be similar laws in the USA as Europe usually follows the USA after a while when it comes to motor vehicles.

Comment: Actually, our warranties protect the consumer much better than it seems it does in the UK. You do not have to use manufacturer's parts as long as the parts are OEM quality. You do not have to go to a manufacturer's repair facility to get something fixed, as long as the person fixing it is certified (this would seem stupid though, because if you are having a warranty item, wouldn't you have the manufacturer do it for free?). You can do maintenance items yourself, as long as you can prove it was done. Much, much easier on the consumer.